# cURL via PHP works on certain sites and on some others don't work?

Tags: php, curl

```
<?php
  $url = 'https://adidas.com/us/';
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  $data = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
  echo $data;
?>
```

I'm just trying to display the contents via cURL, and when I try https://www.google.com/ or another website, it works just fine, however on the adidas site, it timesout?

Thanks!

Comment: I've also tried to curl adidas.com it seems like adidas moves their webpage to different region so your server must be an US based ip. Otherwise you will get an error.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `curl_getinfo` call and you'll see more useful information

```
<?php
  $url = 'https://adidas.com/us/';
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  $data = curl_exec($curl);
  print_r(curl_getinfo($curl));
  curl_close($curl);
  echo $data;
?>
```

In this case, after a minute it times out and `curl_getinfo` returns `http_code` of 0. This means that a connection can not be established.

Comment: `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` is also useful

Answer (score 0):

`adidas.com` is apparently inaccessible through `HTTPS`. It works through `HTTP` and redirects to `http://www.adidas.com/us/`. This address works through `HTTPS` too.

Use `https://www.adidas.com/us/` instead.

Comment: I tried running the http version, and the script ended, but is there any reason `curl_exec` returns an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

You get an empty string for `curl_exec` (for http link) because response code is 301 Moved Permanently. Body of the HTTP response is empty.